# Should I be using unique_ptr if I'm not trying to manage the memory of the object I'm pointing at?

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have three classes: A, B, C

in class A there is a `vector<vector<B>>`

in class C there is a `vector<unique_ptr<B>>` the ptrs in the C vector simply points at the elements of the 2d vector in class A.

I only want a reference to these elements and I don't want to have to create new memory with these pointers (not sure if that is what the unique_ptrs are doing).

In this case, would I be better off just using raw pointers?

EDIT: I don't want the objects I'm pointing at to be deleted when the vector is deleted (when the ptrs go out of scope)

Comment: "*I don't want the objects I'm pointing at to be deleted when the vector is deleted (when the ptrs go out of scope)*" Then don't put those objects in a vector because objects in a vector are deleted when the vector is deleted. Since `vector` is a container that owns its contents and `unique_ptr` is an owning pointer, you should never have a `unique_ptr` to an object in a `vector`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  But I need to be able to access that vector in class A, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @davidbak: I think David Schwartz was saying not to have the `unique_ptr` *point into* the contents of a `vector`, not that `vector`s can't store `unique_ptr`. The `vector` owns its contents, and a `unique_ptr` trying to claim ownership of an element in it is heap corruption waiting to happen.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - dang, read question and comments wrong.  Deleting my other comments in shame.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OK I completely misread "you should never have a unique_ptr to an object in a vector". Removing my comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (well, shouldn't unless you love corrupting all the things) use `unique_ptr` to refer to objects not allocated via `new` (or implicitly via `std::make_unique`).

Using raw pointers isn't a particularly good idea either unless you fully initialize `A`'s 2D `vector` before initializing `C`'s, and then never resize it after that; resizing would invalidate your pointers, causing undefined behavior should you attempt to read from them.

I'd recommend 1 of 2 options, depending on what works best in your scenario:

1. Use a `vector<vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>>` in `A` (populating it with types allocated via `std::make_shared`) and make `C`'s `vector` either `vector<std::shared_ptr<B>>` (if deleting from `A` should not affect `C` and there aren't reference cycles involved) or `vector<std::weak_ptr<B>>` (if deleting from `A` should remove the reference in `C`)
2. If `C` points to a logical index in `A` (where changing the value in `A`'s `vector` should change what is seen through `C`), change `C` to hold:

   a. A reference to `A`'s `vector` (or `A` itself)

   b. A `vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>>` where each `pair` defines the indices to use to look up the associated value in `A`'s `vector`.

Option 2 means `A` doesn't have to change much, if at all (aside from making sure `C` can see its `vector`); the `vector` remains value based, so using a value in it remains only two random access indirections, not the 3-4 required when using `shared_ptr` (`std::make_shared` means it's effectively 3, where manually calling `new` and `std::shared_ptr` is 4).

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime if the `B` objects is managed by the vector in `A`. That means there is no need to wrap a `unique_ptr` around them. In fact, that's an error if your `unique_ptr`s are not created using a no-op deleter; in that case, they will delete the objects, and then the vector will delete them again.

Since `C` just needs to observe the objects, you can use raw pointers. Non-owning raw pointers (meaning pointers you never call `delete` on) are fine.

However, this kind of long-term raw pointer can be hard to reason about. Are the objects pointed to still valid? How do you know? You might want to instead add an API to `A` that provides access to the objects and only access them in `C` when needed, without storing any pointers to them.